# pass data to view controller using storyboard segue iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I know there are lots of postings about this but I have tried everything and nothing has worked.  So I have tried to pass an object between two view controllers, to a DBKIngredientsViewController embedded in a navigation item.  I have a push segue with the identifier "showIngredientsSegue" to the DBKIngredientsViewController.  The error message I receive is:

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DBKIngredientsViewController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a92450'

The view controller to which I am segueing is embedded in a  navigation controller, which I think is messing it up.  What's the way around this?  To be clear, the DBKViewController is already embedded in a navigation controller, and the push segue pushes the DBKViewController, not the navigation controller embedding it.  I have tried it different ways but none seem to work.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showIngredientsSegue"]){
        
        UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        DBKIngredientsViewController *controller = (DBKIngredientsViewController *)navController.topViewController;
        controller.targetRecipe = selectedRecipe;
    }
}
```

[image: IMG]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that `segue.destinationViewController` is a `UINavigationController`? It seems like it's just a `DBKIngredientsViewController` so this should work:

```
DBKIngredientsViewController *controller = (DBKIngredientsViewController *)segue.destinationViewController
```

Also if `DBKViewController` already has a navigation controller then you do not need a second one if you are pushing `DBKIngredientsViewController`. You would only need a second one if you are modally displaying `DBKIngredientsViewController`.

Comment: hmm, I tried that.  This is the error:
 Warning: Attempt to present <DBKIngredientsViewController: 0x8b6d430> on <UINavigationController: 0x8d75570> while a presentation is in progress!

Comment: Then the problem is how you are presenting the view controller. How is the view controller presented? Are you dismissing a modal and pushing at the same time or pushing twice at the same time?

Comment: I guess it's two pushes?  The first view controller is pushed on top of the root navigation view controller.  I'm then pushing the DBKIngredientsViewController in the segue.

Comment: Yeah just remove the second `UINavigationController`, I've updated my answer.

Comment: I took out the second UINavigationController but now I have a new problem.. nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
2013-11-02 01:32:09.549 RecipesWithCore[21666:70b] Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.

Comment: Is the segue happening twice for some reason? Are you calling it via the code as well maybe on cell selection?

Comment: Yes, you got it.  Thanks for the help.  Did not realize that I connected the segue in storyboard via the cell selection, as opposed to the view.  Now it works.

Comment: Awesome. Just translating the errors :) I ran into a lot of these same issues when I started iOS as well.